# Using Google Maps to gather company address?

Tags: php, maps

I have a page where X person writes in their company name, for example: "BCF, Cannon Hill"

I want to make a script which will look this company up via Google Maps and return the first result (address).

So for example; they enter `"BCF, Cannon Hill"`

Our script returns:

```
1177 Wynnum Road, Cannon Hill QLD 4170, Australia
```

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=bcf,+cannon+hill

How can I do this? Is there a PHP api or anything?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Although it's against the google terms of use, you could scrape out just that item as follows (or maybe the Places API would be a better solution depending on your need: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$input=addslashes($_REQUEST["search"]);
if(strlen($input)>0){
$input=str_replace(" ","+",$input);
$url="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=".$input;
$file=file_get_contents($url);
$start=strpos($file,"pp-headline-item pp-headline-address")+44;
$end=strpos($file,"</span>",$start);
$firstResult=substr($file,$start,$end-$start);
echo $firstResult;
}
else{
    echo "You must add the 'search' parameter";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you need to tie into the Telstra Yellow pages database to get all business addresses in Australia?